# Wildcard subdomain redirect to folder without changing the url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, apache-2.4, redirect, wildcard-subdomain

So I got my htaccess file set up, it look like this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

# MAGIC
RewriteCond $1 !/$
RewriteCond $1 !\.
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /$1/ [R=301,L]
# //MAGIC

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^([a-z0-9][-a-z0-9]+)\.domain\.com
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subdomains/
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomains/%1/$1 [P,NC,QSA]
```

I work quite fine, it nicely directs **phpmyadmin.domain.com** to **phpmyadmin.domain.com/subdomains/phpmyadmin/**

But I think it is quite ugly it shows that in the url. So I want it to redirect it silently so it still points to 
**phpmyadmin.domain.com/subdomains/phpmyadmin/** but the client can only see **phpmyadmin.domain.com**

I've been looking around but I couldn't find anything that worked like I wanted it to work. Does anyone have an idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

You're working too hard. Try using the [`VirtualDocumentRoot`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#virtualdocumentroot) with a variable. [`%1`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html#interpol) will use the first part of the domain, or `%-3` will use the third to last part (both represents the same for your case). You'll need to enable the module [`mod_vhost_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html) for this to work.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  VirtualDocumentRoot /var/www/%1
  ServerName www.domain.com
  ServerAlias *.domain.com
</VirtualHost>
```